# How can I debug a Borland BCC55 compiled EXE using visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, borland-c

I have two visual studio projects (A, B) which create dlls. This dlls are loaded by program C which is compiled using BCC55. I have the source code for all the projects. How can I debug A,B and C together ?

Comment: Since you have the source, compile with Visual Studio instead of Borland.

Comment: the code doesn't get compiled with visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, you can't.

Being able to debug, by which you probably mean using breakpoints and having the IDE stop on a certain line in the source code when there's an exception or other error etc. is not just about having the source, but having the debug symbols. This data can either be embedded in the binary, which is usually the case with a debug build, or in a separate file, but either way it is generated (or not generated) at compile time. And Microsoft has its own format which is different from Borland's format and so on.

And on top of all that, BCC 5.5 is quite dated, to say the least. If I were you, I'd take care of the VS build errors, build everything in VS and take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I too would have built everything using VS but my use case is a bit different. I am working on hooking and intercepting executables. My hooking/interception framework is built using visual studio and it needs to support binaries built with other compilers too. There are couple of issues when hooking a program compiled with borland which I need to fix. I knew that it would be difficult to debug all the programs together. Just wanted to check if anyone knows of any method to achieve this.